# Compare passwords while resting password in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bcrypt

While registration time password is encrypted and stored in database(mongoDB).
To encrypt this password I have used **bcrypt.hash** in model. Now I am doing reset password using node.js How to compare encrypted password and user entered password.

### user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var UserSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
email: {type: String, required: true, select: true},
mobile: {type: String, required: true, select: true},
password: {type: String, required: true, select: true},
active:{ type: 'Boolean', default: false},
generatedOtp:{ type: String},
resetPasswordToken: String,
resetPasswordExpires: Date,
//occasiontype: {type: String, required: true, select: true},
//date: {type: Date  , required: true, select: true}
});




UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
var user = this;

if(!user.isModified('password')) return next();


bcrypt.hash(user.password, null, null, function(err, hash){
    if(err) return next(err);

    user.password = hash;
    next();
});
});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(password){
var user = this;
//console.log(user.password + password);
return bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
}
UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

### api.js

```
router.post('/resetPasswordafterlogin',function(req,res){
    var uId = ObjectId(req.body.userId);
    var oldPassword = req.body.formdata.oldPassword;
    var newPassword = req.body.formdata.newPassword;


    console.log(req.body.formdata.validPassword)
    return res.json({})
});
```

[image: Form]

### controller.js

```
(function ()
{
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.security')
    .controller('SecurityController', SecurityController);

/** @ngInject */
//SecurityController.$inject = ['$http', '$location'];
function SecurityController($http, $location, $rootScope, $localStorage)
{
    var vm = this;
    vm.uId = $localStorage._id;

    vm.save =  function(userData){

        $http({
            url: 'http://192.168.2.8:7200/api/resetPasswordafterlogin',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {userId: vm.uId, formdata: userData}
        }).then(function(res) {
            console.log("success");
        }, function(error) {
            alert(error.data);
        });
    };   

    vm.cancel = function(){
        $location.url('/pages/dashboard');
    }

}
})();
```

So now I have to compare this oldPassword with encrypted password in user model. How to do this?

Comment: Hashing !== encryption. Encryption is reversible, a hash isn't. That's why you want to use hashing for passwords.

Comment: then how to do that?

Comment: I don't know specifically how node's bcrypt implementation handles salts. Typically you 1) get the user record from the database by email/username, 2) hash the entered password with the salt from the hash from the database and 3) compare the hashes.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using following in node.js.

### api.js

```
router.post('/resetPasswordafterlogin',function(req,res){
    var uId = ObjectId(req.body.userId);
    var oldPassword = req.body.formdata.oldPassword;
    var newPassword = req.body.formdata.newPassword;
            
        async.waterfall([
        function(done) {
            User.findOne({ _id : uId}, function(err, user) {
                var validPassword = user.comparePassword(oldPassword);
                if (!validPassword) {
                    var message = {
                        message: 'Incorrect password.'
                    };
                    done(null, message);
                }else if (user, done){
                    user.password = newPassword;
                                        
                    user.save(function(err) {
                        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                            done(err, user);
                        });
                    });
                    
                    
                    var message = {
                        message: 'Success! Your password has been changed.'
                    };
                    done(null, message);
                }
            });
        }
    ], function(err, result){
        if (err) return next(err);
        return res.json({
            result: result.message
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the simple function to compare the password:

```
exports.comparePassword = (passwordToCompare, dbPassword, callback) => {
  console.log("comparePassword", passwordToCompare)
  bcrypt.compare(passwordToCompare, dbPassword, (err, isMatch) => {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    else
      callback(null, isMatch);
  });
};
```